# How to attach Windows Debug Logger to spdlog

Tags: visual-studio-2015, spdlog

I wondering how to attach windows debug logger to [spdlog](https://github.com/gabime/spdlog), which claim that it support Windows Debug Log (OutputDebugString)

I can't find any example to do that.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Found answer from spdlog owner: Try using [msvc_sink](https://github.com/gabime/spdlog/blob/master/include/spdlog/sinks/msvc_sink.h)